# Gmail closes when i touch icon in blue address bar

Tags: gmail

I'VE have a dgm t909s tablet android 4, when I am in the gmail app and I press the icon in the blue address bar a box pops up with ( unfortunatly gmail has stopped) and closes down the app.
Anyone got any answers please

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "the icon in the blue address bar". Could you describe it more fully or post a screenshot to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: in the gmail mobile (tablet) app - you open a email up, when it opens at the top of it there is a blue address that has the email subject in it and at the left hand side there is a small icon of a persons head & shoulders (This is apparantly the sender) now if you touch this icon -a box opens with unfortunately gmail has stopped with the option o f report or ok- I would post some sceen shots but I havn't got a clue how to attach them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your tablet is missing the 'Contacts' or 'People' app (or has one customized by the manufacturer, which doesn't understand the same *intents*). Since every OHA-certified Android device has it, Gmail is trying to launch it without checking whether it exists, and that's what's going wrong.

If you disabled the app yourself (by clicking **Disable** in the app's page in **Settings** → **Apps**), then you have to re-enable it to avoid this problem.

If the Gmail app was pre-installed on your tablet, then this is a system integration error. You should complain to the manufacturers and ask them to release an update to fix the problem.

Until then, or if you installed Gmail yourself on a tablet that doesn't support it, you should be able to fix the problem if you can [find and install the original Contacts or People app](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps).

Comment: WOW! you know your stuff mate.The gmail app was pre-installed so I need to speak to dgm about it. I think next time I buy a tablet I will spend a bit more and get a well known one. Thanks

Comment: just been in touch with dgm they asked me to do a factory reset to see if it fixes it but that didn't work so they have asked me to return it to them

Comment: That sounds like a scripted response. It's possible they've already fixed the error in their ROM, so they're going to flash an updated ROM onto your device. More likely, they're going to run a standard hardware test on it. As the problem's a programming error, this test will report that the device has no fault, whereupon they may try to charge you for sending it back unnecessarily. You might want to check what they intend to do before you send them the device.